# What does the "location" number represent in this BigQuery error message: ' (position 14) starting at location 211312420'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

This was the error message that was in my error stream. A particular value of string type was being assigned to a column of integer type, the full error message:

> Could not parse 'Employee' as int for field sector_code (position 16) starting at location 443622571

This message is a bit cryptic to me, at first I thought the location number was the row number however the aforementioned number is more then the number of rows in the table. I personally tried to search for the answer on google but could not find an answer.

Edit: I am loading in a csv from google cloud storage

Comment: Are you attempting to parse an avro file? If you are, what byte block size are you using?

Comment: @FridayPush Sorry I forgot to mention, I am parsing a csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this for a CSV? The current format for those errors is:

`Could not parse '<value>' as <type> for <field> (position <column>) starting at location <byte offset in input>`